# How to read body of table from a separate file?

Tags: input, latex

I want to read/input the body of a table from a separate file.
But it failed.
How can I do it.
The below is an example

Main tex file: **Main.tex**

```
%main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Table test.

1. Insert a full table

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
c & d \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

2. Input the body of table from a seperate file

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} 
\input{table}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Table body file: **table.tex**

```
%table.tex
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
c & d \\
\hline
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
(La)TeX-related questions are better asked at [tex.se]. Your question has been flagged so that it gets migrated there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Capture the table contents in `table.tex` in a macro before processing it inside a `tabular`. For this, use the [`catchfile` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/catchfile):

[image]

```
%main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,catchfile}
\begin{filecontents*}{table.tex}
%table.tex
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
c & d \\
\hline 
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Table test.

1. Insert a full table

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  a & b \\
  \hline
  c & d \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

2. Input the body of table from a seperate file

\CatchFileDef{\mytable}{table.tex}{}% table.tex > \mytable
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} 
  \mytable
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to put multiple tables (bodies) in the same table.tex file and select the right one each time I want to add a new table to my main document?

Comment: @a_bet: Consider using the [`catchbetweentags` package](//ctan.org/pkg/catchbetweentags). You'll have to provide some form of reference for the respective table bodies using tags: `%<*tag>`...`%</tag>`.